# Aptana project types not available

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, aptana

I have recently installed the Aptana plugin for Eclipse as I wish to learn Ruby and Ruby on Rails, it doesn't seem to have changed anything. Usually when I install a plugin of the sort, there will be new project types under the "New Project" menu, but none appeared. I checked tutorials online and they suggest that there should be new project types as seen in the image below, taken from a tutorial.
[image]

Instead, I see the same options I did before.
[image]

I wondered if the plugin didn't install, but when I try to install it again, It says it's already installed. I am using Eclipse Juno Service Release 2 with a 64-bit Windows 7 operating system and the version of the plugin from the URL given on the Aptana website (http://download.aptana.com/studio3/plugin/install). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that's happening. Here's a suggestion for how to get around it.

You might be better off installing and running the standalone Aptana Studio product. It would be a separate installation on your desktop, and thus wouldn't have the same settings as any Eclipse installation you already had, and would be more space on your hard drive. But probably there isn't much you would share between Ruby/Rails development and other development, and it's not that much space.

I've done it both ways - installed Aptana into an Eclipse I've already got, and installed the standalone version - and now I would only do standalone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong in the first place, but after I installed the Aptana plugin, I installed the PyDev plugin. I think this removed the Aptana plugin because of conflicting dependencies (I don't know why it wouldn't tell me, though). I tried installing the Aptana plugin again and it told me there was a conflicting dependency with the PyDev plugin, so I uninstalled it and reinstalled the Aptana plugin. It works now.